# .htaccess conditional rewrite and file structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

To break it down, this is how my sitemap looks like.

```
http://website.com/home
http://website.com/contact
http://website.com/support
```

With my index.php handler handling the GET statement index.php?home, index.php?contact, and index.php?support

Currently, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php?%1  [L]
```

So far this works great, however it's limited. I'm integrating a mini blog I designed in PHP that would accept query string to look as so:

```
http://site.com/blog.php?y=2013&m=02&d=12&title=welcome-to-site-blog
```

Now, I would like to keep the sites root file structure AND also integrate a blogging file structure. Hopefully to look like this:

```
http://site.com/2013/02/12/welcome-to-site-blog
```

Any help would be great. I understand that conditional statements will be required, but I have little to no experience with htaccess.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Just use `\d+` in place of `.*`. There are more exact duplicates; just hard to find with likewise unspecific question titles.

Comment: What does the \d+ do exactly? After I replace .*, I get 404's unless the query string is a number.

Comment: I did, still getting a 404 with it. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Would you mind doing a pastebin example? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !blog\.php                           [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .  blog.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4         [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://site.com/var1/var2/var3/var4`

To:

`http://site.com/blog.php?key1=var1&key2=var2&key3=var3&key4=var4`

All `varN` strings are assumed to be variable while the script name `blog.php` is fixed but can be any name. Replace all instances in the rule set if changed.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,NC]` with `[R=301,L,NC]`.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping you would answer! Now, that works perfectly - however, how would I incorporate both this exact example with my other page structure? Right now, this only works for if you have /year/month/date but the website also uses `http://site.com/company` and redirects to `http://site.com/index.php?company`.

Comment: If I understand right, you want to exclude from the rule some URLs like: `http://site.com/company` and maybe others. Right? Are there more? If so, what's the pattern that identifies them, if any, and do all of them go to `index.php` in root directory?.